# Module/Component with adjusted content in different articles

Tags: joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, joomla-module

I maintain the website of my sports club. I recently switched to joomla and try now to set up the pages. Although I'm pretty new to joomla and the extension development, I have experience in php/MYSQL and already developed some minor modules.

What I want to do, is having a page/article for every team of the club. The pages look all about the same. They are holding further information of the players, scores, etc. (and maybe later some kind of news-box, where the coach of the team can post stuff). All the information is in a couple of DB tables for each team.
Up to now I created some modules, which show the content the way I want and it works fine for one team. I install the module, connect it to the team page and enter the name of the DB table in the backend of the module. 
But I have to do that for every team, so I get 20 modules of the same kind that just differ in the DB name parameter and pages on which they are displayed. It would be a pain to update every module each time.

Is it possible to get the DB table name for a variable(?) from the article? My research wasn't successful on this matter. Would it be better to develop a component, but that would lead to the same problem, right? Do I need to create a plugin which holds all the information of each team, and then the module is the same on each team page but gets the DB table name from the plugin?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up develop a component and when I set up a new team, I select this component for the menu item. I the back end I can then select one of the teams in the database. 
The modules for the teams are displayed in this component and get the team information from the component parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a CCK so you can define what a team page is, then enter the content in the appropriate fields for display. Without knowing specifics, you could probably do what you want with a combination of K2 and K2 BNR Content module. That would reduce the number of modules to a single instance of each module that loads the content related to the team page you are viewing. No custom code necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I took a look on K2 and i think I will use it, but for another task.
For my initial purpose, I would still like to create some kind of plugin which provides for the module the necessary information (e.g. DB name), if the that's a proper way to do it.
What kind of plugin should I use (content plugin?) and how can I access the data of the plugin with the module/component?
Thanks

Comment: You probably don't need a plugin at all. You should be able to do it with a module. Keep in mind, in Joomla a plugin is used to modify or add to content based on an event happening. A module displays content in a module position and a component displays content in the main content area. There a bunches of custom module tutorials, that would be a good place to start.

Comment: I didn't intent to use a plugin at the beginning. I already created the module. The problem is, that I don't want to have 20 modules (for each team one) that only differ in the name of the SQL table it get's the data from. So my idea was that the plugin provides the SQL table name for the module. But now I found out that a module could get a parameter from a component, so maybe it's the better solution to store the SQL table name as a parameter of the component (in which the module is displayed)